# For loop to input strings in vector using getline

Tags: c++, string, vector

So I have an assignment for school, I need to declare a vector of strings 
then use a for loop to input names into the vector using get line. This code is what I have so far, I was trying to make a variable for a location in my vector, then input a string into the vector based on the value of my variable. Im using C++.

What Im wondering is: whats the flaw in my logic?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;
#include <string>;
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<string> name_list(10);
int n;
for (name_list[n]; cin.getline >> name_list[n]; ++n)
    cin >> name_list[n];
cout << name_list[n];
int stop; cin >> stop;
return 0;
}
```

EDIT::: 
So I figured it out! Thank you 0x499602D2, You kinda set me on the right way. the code I came up with is this::

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<string> name_list(11);
int n = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < 11; ++n);
getline(cin, name_list[n]);
cout << name_list[n];

int stop; cin >> stop;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` is uninitialized. Try `int n = 0;`. Also, your code can go beyond the bounds of `name_list`.

Comment: I initialized `n` and it still wont compile?

Comment: Well, `cin`, `vector` and `string` aren't declared. And [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is a member function. You should try to follow some examples on how to correctly use the standard library. Randomly typing code isn't going to be very productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is `n` uninitialized, you're also doing `cin.getline >> name_list[n]` which shouldn't even compile as far as I know. `getline` is a member function of `std::cin` that reads a line from input into a character array. It's not needed here as we are trying to read into a vector.

Moreover, since you want to get names from the user input into each slot in the vector, attempting to retrieve a *line* with `getline` also wouldn't make sense.

`n` needs to be initialized to an integer that when access with `name_list[n]`, will give us the start of the vector (that would be `0`), and instead of `getline`, we use the operator `>>` to get each whitespace separated input. Like this:

```c++
for (int n = 0; std::cin >> name_list[n]; ++n)
    ; // empty
```

A statement isn't needed within the for loop body as its already been done in the loop parameters.

---

Another thing you need to look out for is overrunning the size of the vector. You initialized `name_list` with a size of `10`, and if the user enters in, say, `11` names, accessing an index with `name_list[n]` will cause [**Undefined Behavior**](http://en.cppreference.com/book/undefined_behavior) in your program, which is a special way of saying your program will be invalid.

It's better to use the `at()` member function as it will throw an [exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions%E2%80%8E) if you try to access an out-of-bounds address:

```c++
for (int n = 0; std::cin >> name_list.at(n); ++n)
//                                   ^^^^^^
    ;
```

Comment: Perhaps I dont understand my assignment then? Im supposed to use get line to input the names, but getline is unable to do so? Also, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Dlorwisdom `getline` *can* do so, but I was under the impression that you simply wanted to get each *word* from user input into the vector, not an entire *line*. If you need to get a line, however, in C++ it's recommended that you use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), a function that takes a line from the stream into an `std::string` object. It's different from the member function `getline` as it is a free function and takes `std::string` as a parameter rather than a `char` array.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me figure out getline, I didnt understand that I had to create a string variable and use that as the parameter!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize n=0 and in the second for parameter you might wanna move the cin into the loop and replace it with i < 10 because otherwise the loop would not know when to stop